# Update viewmodel when value changes in dynamically added input in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have been working on KnockoutJS since two weeks and I am trying to add inline editing in a grid using KnockOutJS and jQuery. My html:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Excerpts</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Articles">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Excerpts, event: { dblclick: $root.editField }"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Excerpts, event: { dblclick: $root.editField }"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Content, event: { dblclick: $root.editField }"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My JS:

```
function Articles(Articles) {
    this.id = ko.observable(Articles.id);
    this.Title = ko.observable(Articles.Title);
    this.Excerpts = ko.observable(Articles.Excerpts);
    this.Content = ko.observable(Articles.Content);
}
var ViewModel = {
    Articles: ko.observableArray
        ([new Articles(id = 1, Title = "Title1", Excerpts = "Excerpts1", Content = "Content1")]),
    loadArticles: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Articles(Articles);
    },
    editField: function (d, e) {
        var currentEle = $(e.target);
        var value = $(e.target).html();
        $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
        $(currentEle).find('input').focus();
        $(currentEle).find('input').keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(currentEle).html($(currentEle).find('input').val().trim());
                //CallAjaxWithData('/MTB_Articles/EditArticle', 'POST', ko.toJSON(d), null, null); // To update data in server
            }
        });

        $(document).click(function () {
            if ($(currentEle).find('input').val() != null) {
                $(currentEle).html($(currentEle).find('input').val().trim());
                //CallAjaxWithData('/MTB_Articles/EditArticle', 'POST', ko.toJSON(d), null, null); // To update data in server
            }
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
ViewModel.loadArticles();
```

Whenever the user double clicks on any td in the grid, I am adding an input field dynamically using the `editField` function and binding the updated value to the `td` again when user presses enter key or clicks somewhere else on the page. The parameter `d` in the `editField` function gives the current viewmodel object. I have to update the corresponding value in the parameter `d` when user edits the value in a particular column, convert `d` to json format and send it to server via `ajax` call to be updated in the database. The changes made by the user should be reflected in the view model( the parameter `d`). So how can we update the view model using dynamically added controls?

[JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/seadrag0n/ADttL/2/)

Comment: try this fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ADttL/24/ should do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a more 'ko-ish' way that will make it easier for you.

KO is mostly declarative, and you're mixing declarative and procedural (jQuery) code.

To make it declarative, and much easier to implement, do the following:

- add an `editing` observable property to your `Articles`. Initialize it to false
- inside the `<td>`'s show either the text, or a data-bound input, depending on the value of the `editing` observable property
- use the double click event, to set `editing` to true
- use the enter key press to do what you need (ajax) with the values in your model, and set the `editing` to false again

You can do it like this:

```
 <td>
   <!-- ko ifnot: editing, text: Excerpts --><!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko if: editing -->
      <input class="thVal" type="text" data-bind="value: Excerpts" />
   <!--- /ko -->
 </td>
```

Or even shorter:

```
 <td>
   <!-- ko ifnot: editing, text: Excerpts --><!-- /ko -->
   <input class="thVal" type="text" data-bind="value: Excerpts, if: editing" />
 </td>
```

Comment: the `Articles` object in my case will be dynamic based on server side(ASP.NET MVC to be specific) model classes and will be generated dynamically.Can I add the `editing` observable property in the viewModel itself and use it or is there any other way?

Comment: can you also please post JSFiddle for you answer.